# React-Native : ScrollView not showing the full content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I'm building an app with React-Native and for my Home Page im using the ScrollView but it doesn't show the full content. I have e header on the top so that may be blocking the full content or i don't know.

The code :

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Content from "../components/Content/content";
import Header from "../components/Header/header";
import Carousel1 from "../components/Carousel/index";
import Buttons from "../components/Buttons/buttons";

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
let drawerLabel = "Home";
return { drawerLabel };
};

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Header {...this.props} />
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
      <Carousel1 />
      <Content />
      <Buttons />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9"
}
});
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Look at expo snack example: https://snack.expo.io/@professorxii/scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Try it with react native Flatlist instead of ScrollView:
 [React-native Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

Comment: i had this problem once and i solved it with Flatlist ... it was almost the same with a header, i had flex: 1, flex-direction: column on main container, also i put the Flatlist in another container form some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`contentContainerStyle`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle) instead of `style` with [`ScrollView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html).

Since I don't have access to your `Carousel1` , `Content`, and `Buttons` component to give you a certain answer, I suggest you try the following:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Header {...this.props} />
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection:"column" }}>
      <Carousel1 />
      <Content />
      <Buttons />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Report back with your results.

Answer (score 0):

Remove style={{flex:1}} from ScrollView and see